# get emails for last x number of hours in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am using "get emails v3" action in "outlook.com" for logic apps. I want to search emails  based on subject filters in todays date only. I want following search criteria where I want emails between two times.

```
((receivedDateTime:@{utcNow()})) BETWEEN (receivedDateTime:@{addToTime(utcNow(), 1, 'Day')})
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing it was clear that this is because of the format of `receivedDateTime` is not as same as the format of utcNow(). To achieve your requirement, you need to compare the dates in same format using condition. Below is how I to achieve your requirement using condition action.

*Left side Condition*

```
formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['receivedDateTime'],'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

*Right side Condition*

```
formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

[image]

Here is the complete flow of my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Below is the code view of my Logic App

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Email",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each_2')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "greaterOrEquals": [
                                        "@formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['receivedDateTime'],'dd/MM/yyyy')",
                                        "@formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'dd/MM/yyyy')"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "lessOrEquals": [
                                        "@formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['receivedDateTime'],'dd/MM/yyyy')",
                                        "@formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM/dd/yyyy')"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_emails_(V3)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_emails_(V3)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v3/Mail",
                    "queries": {
                        "fetchOnlyFlagged": false,
                        "fetchOnlyUnread": false,
                        "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": false,
                        "folderPath": "Inbox",
                        "importance": "Any",
                        "includeAttachments": false
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Email",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_emails_(V3)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly then this is the sort approach you need to take.

[image: Get Emails v3]

There's an additional parameter to that connector called `Search Query`.

In there, you can put an expression that looks like the following ...

```
received>@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}
```

You're close, if you look at the doco though, the name of the field is different to what comes back in the response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/search-query-parameter

You may just need to play around with the formula to give you exactly what you want given the response is all in UTC.  I think -1 day is the easiest but it may not be perfect for you.

Comment: That’s ok. You ultimately need to select the approach that you were happiest with and ultimately implemented. It’s not always about being correct because there are often multiple approaches. I preferred my shorter approach but that’s ok. 